# Newsletter pop-up with cookie after delay

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup, delay, newsletter

The problem that I am facing now is that the pop-up shows immediately and if u didn't close the pop-up but go to a different page the pop-up shows up after the delay of 10 seconds.
So it looks like if the user don't have a cookie yet the pop-up shown immediately, but when he has a cookie it shows after 10 seconds.

I'm trying to make a newsletter pop-up that's shows up after a delay of 10 seconds. But only if the user doesn't have a cookie yet. Otherwise, the pop-up won't show.

I'm not so known with jQuery so sorry for my messy code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!Cookies.get('alert')) { 
      $('.popup-overlay').show(); 
      Cookies.set('alert', true, { expires: 1 });
    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.popup-overlay').show();
      }, 10000);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Your popup shows immediately with no cookie, so logically the code that shows the popup = no cookie = `if (!Cookies.get(` - so move your `setTimeout` code into the `if` (instead of the `else`) and don't have any code to show immediately.   I'm not sure where the difficulty is, if you've managed to code this.

Comment: Hi freedom, thanks for your reply! I tried that but still no succes... it always shows at the moment. $(document).ready(function(){
 if (!Cookies.get('alert')) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.popup-overlay').show();}, 10000);  }
    Cookies.set('alert', true, { expires: 1 });
});